# Salesforce Confused on what object it is looking for

Tags: custom-object, lookup, custom-field

In our environment, we have two custom `Course` objects, one's identifier is `Course__c` the other is `hed__Course__c`. (Don't ask me why, it's just how it is.)

The one I am focused on is `Course__c`. `Course__c` has a look up field that looks to another `Course__c`, this is for linking translated courses. In my object manager, everything looks correct, the field says the field name is `Course__c`.

However, when I go to assign this value through the API, I get the error `Course: id value of incorrect type`.

Double checking on this, through the lightning portal, I attempted to add the course field manually, it is searching for `hed__Course__c`, not `Course__c`. And when I select `Add New` it gives me the form to create a `hed__Course__c`.

Why would Salesforce get confused on this? The two objects have different names, just the same label... Seems like a bug to me

Comment: The field API name can be `Course__c` while the field looks up to, well, anything. You need to look at the field detail in Object Manager and click through the link to the looked-up object. You'll find it's  `hed__Course__c` unless you've got some kind of other customization confusing things.

Answer (score 0):

Check Course__c.Course__c Lookup Field Definition via Setup> Object Manager > Course > Search fields for "Course"

Ensure that the field actually looks up to the Course__c and not the hed_Course__c object. Chances are the labels for both objects are similar and whoever created the Course__c.Course__c Lookup field accidentally linked to hed_Course__c and not Course__c object.